# Print Bar code using Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that I have to add a Bar Code to.  I have downloaded some free and demo TrueType fonts Code 39, Code 128 and UPC from various sources.   When I print out the report I can see the bar code but it will not scan with my scanner(the scanner works as I have tested it on multiple other bar codes).  Do I need to use something special with Crystal Reports to create a bar code that a scanner can read?

(I have tried printing it on a label printer designed for printing labels so I don't think it is an issue with the paper/resolution)

Comment: Are you exporting it before printing, or are you printing it directly in the native format in the viewer control?

Comment: I am exporting it as a pdf and then sending it to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed most barcodes have checksums and/or leading & trailing characters.

The most simple one is Code 3 of 9. To use it you need to start and end the code with an *.

Examples:

- to print **ABCD** you need to use ***ABCD***

Some characters require to be escaped as well:

- to print **#123**! you need to use ***/C123/A***

More info on [Code 3 of 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39).

Answer (score 4):

Barcodes have check digits embedded in them, and you need to reproduce that in addition to using the font.  I believe there are third party libraries for Crystal that properly format barcodes so they are scannable.

Comment: Have you used one of these 3rd party libraries?  Which one works... Any free??

Comment: I don't do the Crystal stuff around here, but I think we used Azalea.  Some years ago I found a sample for formatting Code128 and adapted for our use.  I don't know of anything free, but some of the formatting rules are available for you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can desing a RPT for your codebar printer, using "Printer Fonts". But you need print using some special code. You can find it at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312690/192389