# Barcode Printing

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports, barcode, barcode-scanner

My client is using SATO CG 408 TT  barcode printer. I want to make my C# application able to print barcodes using this printer. Label sizes are 50mm x 25mm

I tried to search documentation of SATO website and also googled some links, but dint find any satisfactory solutions. Zebra printer have their own languages, so that we dont need to integrate any fonts in reports.

The questions might be silly :P.. but its important to know before I start coding.

Comment: Sato does have SBPL (like Zebra's ZPL or EPL2)

Comment: Please mention it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sato does offer [SBPL](http://www.satoamerica.com/cms/Operator+and+Technical+Manuals/98.html), much like Zebra's ZPL or EPL2 language.

Answer (score 0):

You can desing a RPT for ZEBA, using Printer Fonts. But you need print using some special code. You can find it at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312690/192389